# Passing a JavaScript variable to a html <select> attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I am trying to pass a variable from JavaScript to value attribute of the select tag. Here is my code:

```
<script>

 if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "http://ww") {
     var home_var = "bing.com";
     var home_var = "poem.com";
 } else if (window.location.href.substring(0, 9) === "https://p") {
     var home_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=bing.com";
     var poem_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=poem.com";
 } else {
     var home_var = "1";
     var_poem_var = "2";
 }
 console.log(home_var);

</script>

<select OnChange="window.location.href=this.value">
   <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option>
   <option value=HOME_VAR>Home Page</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, what's the problem?

Comment: Javascript variables can't be used directly in HTML, what you probably want is a proper event handler.

Comment: @TimoSta When selecting the "Home Page" option instead of going to bing.com or https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=bing.com is goes to bing.com/home_var or https://px.multiscreensite.com/home_var.

Comment: @adeneo How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the SELECT after in javascript you can achieve this:

```
<select id="mySelect" OnChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option>
</select>

<script>
    if (window.location.href.substring(0,9) === "http://ww") {
    var home_var = "bing.com";    
    }
    else if (window.location.href.substring(0,9) === "https://p") {
    var home_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=bing.com";
    }
    else {
    var home_var = "1";
    }
    var select= document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Hope Page";
    option.value = home_var;
    select.add(option);
    console.log(home_var);
</script>
```

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/emfvyhq2/

Comment: This appears to work for me but I will personally have to fidle with it a little before giving a definitive answer, thank you!

Comment: No problem.  In this situation you'll need to make sure the javascript runs after the DOM loads.

Comment: Sorry this probably sounds stupid but, what is the DOM and how does it apply?

Comment: The Document Object Model.  If you ran this code locally at it's working for you then you don't have to worry about it.  :)

Comment: Because in its current form it does not work. The select statement need to be before the JavaScript. So currently this gives errors, and therefore is not completely correct.

Comment: Ah, my fault.  I assumed that was a given.  I updated for you.

Answer (score 1):

you could add the element dynamically...

```
<script>
(function() {
    var s = document.getElementById("selector");
    var o = document.createElement("option");
    o.innerHTML = "Home Page";
    o.value = home_var;
    s.appendChild(o);
})();
</script>

<select id="selector" OnChange="window.location.href=this.value">    
    <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear above. That would work but I am trying to do this on a larger scale let me edit my question.

Comment: it will scale, make that a proper function and pass in text and value arguments to the function to create the option element

Comment: Sorry i'm not great at this could you do that for me? Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot, you must use the tools available to you. look at my function, how could you add two arguments to it named 'text' and 'value', then how would you change the statements in that function to use those new values? how do you call that function in your code instead of using variables for every value? _edit_ if you have trouble you may ask more questions

Comment: there are only 3 things you need to do _edit_ if you are still having trouble after a time, I'll help you through the answer and I can give you some good documentation on JavaScript if you would like

Comment: Documentation would be wonderful! Please if you have any I would love to have some!

Comment: honestly I think you could benefit from [starting here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) which covers a lot of the tools available to you in the raw language. then maybe venture into [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), mdn can be thick to those new to the language, but will give you good terms to search for less esoteric information

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
function changeLink(val) {
   if(val === 'HOME_VAR'){
     ... your code logic ...
   }
}

 <select onchange="javascript:changeLink(this.value)">
       <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option>
       <option value="HOME_VAR">Home Page</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of 'changeLink' or how it is soppused to work exactly.

Comment: Here changeLink is a javascript function tied to the onchange event. So this function will execute every time you change the selection. As we are passing this.value to this function you will also have access to the selected option's value. Now if the selected option matches with HOME_VAR you can perform your logic. I am not exactly sure about the requirement here though.

Comment: What do you mean by "the requirement here"?