# Code functioning in JSFiddle environment but not when run otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

So when working on another question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933072/passing-a-javascript-variable-to-a-html-select-attribute/3793317), I got a great answer from @earl3s and a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emfvyhq2/) of the work and it appeared to work fine but when trying to run it in [repl.it](https://repl.it/C4iy/0) it gave me an error, and when trying to run it locally I got an error reading "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null" on line 19. I may be submitting them wrong or the code may be written incorrectly, and insight would be appreciated. Here is the origninal code:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.substring(0,9) === "http://ww") {
    var home_var = "bing.com";    
    }
    else if (window.location.href.substring(0,9) === "https://p") {
    var home_var = "https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php?url=bing.com";
    }
    else {
    var home_var = "1";
    }
    var select= document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Hope Page";
    option.value = home_var;
    select.add(option);
    console.log(home_var);
</script>

<select id="mySelect" OnChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option>Tagged Stuff and Navigation</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your `<select>` isn't there when the script is run, or there is no element with that `id` property; therefore - regardless of which reason - the `select` variable is `null`. For further information please read: "[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)"

Comment: Try moving your script to the end of the body

Comment: Thank you, that is embarrassingly simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), the JavaScript is automatically loaded after the document loads. In [repl](http://repl.it), you had the JavaScript inserted before the dom actually loaded, so `mySelect` didn't exist then. You have to add the JavaScript after the dom loads, i.e. at the end of the `body` tag.

Here's a [working example](https://repl.it/C4iy/1).